# weird Logic error in dataGridView table in C #

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview

I displayed my database tables into dataGridViews, by binding it (from the tiny arrow in top right corner) directly, after that Visual Studio add this line `this.gseTableAdapter.Fill(this.labxDataSet.gse);` the problem is when i try to open the table form (form who displayed this dataGridView) all my project throw's this error [my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kL08.png) the second line and third line work will,
Now i tried to solved this issue by delete this line and display table data from database into dataGridView by using code

```
                
                OleDbDataAdapter da;
                da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gse", con0);
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                da1.Fill(dt1);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
```

this finale code works perfect.
why the first line doesn't work?

Comment: View Detail... ?

Comment: What is kind of detail you need? however,.. I binding table into dataGridView by visual studio its self (there is tiny arrow in the top right datagridview corner), visual studio adds this line ```this.gseTableAdapter.Fill(this.labxDataSet.gse);``` now when i open datagridview form i get error i show it above, i delete this line and write code to display table and this time works, why this line ```this.gseTableAdapter.Fill(this.labxDataSet.gse);``` doesnot work

Comment: Have you initialized gseTableAdapter correctly?

Comment: How? I have only this `public db(){InitializeComponent();}`